# HTML page that save its content, replacing the HTML file itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've to create a html page that auto-save its content.

This page is just a report of the activities of 4 days, that should be updated by some user.

[image]

This page will be used just for 3/4 days (Go live summary status page, and this say i all).. So I don't wanna lose time with backend, but I wanna do something like a trick just on client side, Javascript and HTML.

What I would like to do:

A user access to the page, this page is published on our internal server, update the status of the task and save the page! I thought to do this in two ways:

- Any time I press the save button it just replace the old html content with the new one (replacing the html file itself)
- Save the content in a plan file that will be loaded everytime the page is used, this second option obviously costs a lot of more work..

Any suggestion? I meant, is there something that help me doing this in just few time? I've about 2 days to finish this :(

**UPDATE:** Guys maybe i'm not explaining myself so good, am i thinking so wrong if i suppose just something like this:

*Javascript function that when you click the save button replace the old html server file with the new one containing the row updated...*

Easy easy easy...! I'm a backend developer.. not a lot of experience with beautiful styled front end pages :)

**UPDATE**: By your answer i'm assuming that is NO WAY to do this, without a backend side logic, even if light one, but its not possible to achieve this just with a client side scripting.. I already thought at this, but i was hoping there is some kind of trick that allows to do this without place anything on the server side.. :(

Comment: What you want is a progressive web app. Here is some kind of documentation: https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

Comment: Yhea it sounds really intersting, but i would like to keep it simple, just using javascript... I meant should not be so hard to find a javascript function that just save the html page content in an html file and save it to the filesystem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, because we can use PHP we decided to do this:
we put this in a file called "prova.php" and we launch this. This file shows the content of 'file.html' and save in 'salva.php' sending the data to save.

```
 <?php include('file.html');?> 

 some added string
 </div> 

 <button onclick="save()">SAVE</button> 

 <script> 


 function save(){ 

 var newData=document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML; 
 $.post( "salva.php", { data: newData} ); 
 } 
 </script>
```

The file to save called salva.php, receive the string and save in an existing file called "file.html".

```
<?php


$stringa=$_POST['data'];

$ourFileName = "file.html";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($ourFileHandle,$stringa);
fclose($ourFileHandle);


?>
```

file.html is a file that contains nothing at the beginning

Comment: I will update the question with the final one... it is based on the Ciro structure.... I've to say thanks to this guy CiroRa, one of the most gentle person i find on stack-overflow!!! LOVELY

Answer (score 1):

You can do a timed ajax request every 2 minutes asking for new content and replacing that into the `<body>` tag.

I recommend to use jQuery for this as it helps you do this pretty easily:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I can also use simply a save button, i don't have to manage concurrent access... Can i find some sample somewhere? By the way now i'm looking at you suggestion...

Comment: If you have example, you can find it easily on the web, i will be sooooo glad :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) to store the data in the user's local end.
And its pretty easy and supported by most modern browsers.

There are two "mechanisms" for using Web Storage.

> 1. `sessionStorage` maintains a separate storage area for each given origin that's available for the duration of the page session (as long as the browser is open, including page reloads and restores)
> 2. `localStorage` does the same thing, but persists even when the browser is closed and reopened.

**Update:-** If you want to store data on server but donot want to bother with full fledged database servers then maybe you could use "SQLite". Basically its just runs off of a file.

Comment: Mmmhh... looking at the documentation this permit to me to save on the client side, but i need to save the content to the server, does it support also this?

Comment: Umm... Nope, From the Question I understood that you dont want to store data on back-end, but if you want to do so then you could use `SQLite`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button Writer</title>
    </head>

    <body onload="read()">
         <!--<button onclick="writeInFile()">Save</button> -->
         <input type="button" id="somebutton" onclick="addText()">
         <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
         <div id="text2"></div>
    </body>


    //read a file and write content in text2 div, please set your path
<script>

function read(){
var xhr;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;};
xhr.open("GET","file.txt"); //SET YOUR PATH
xhr.send();
}

function addText()
        {
            document.getElementById('text2').innerHTML += document.getElementById('myText').value;
        }



</script>
</html>
```

To write in file you should use AJAX + PHP. If you want I'll tell you how

Comment: Yes please CiroRa! But the problem with PHP is that i dont have any server running on the Server side, it's the Jenkins unix Server so, it will be a mess to deploy an application, is there any Lightwheight solution to assume..

Comment: Node.js provides a lot of function. What do you think to install on your server? https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: Ok wait, i've this running on the server:
[build@REMJenkinsServer01 ~]$   php --version
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Sep 10 2014 05:27:26)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

Comment: Can you be so gentle to guide me through the step to do, I'm quite intuitive about these stuff, but its a little bit delicated server so i don't have the possiblity to proceed as i use to do "playing around..

Comment: Everything work... i just think that you miss the write part :)

Comment: Not yet, it works, but it does not do what i want... First i think the read is un-useful, i don't need it, i meant i just have to write directly to the php file when save it, and then maybe call a refresh of the page...Are you able to help more? Or should i walk on my feet now?

Comment: have you decided to introduce PHP? the read is necessary to load content from file, there is no way to write without installing some other stuff....

Comment: Ok, could you help to guide my through this...? I got to update some div into the page and then rewrite to the server html/php page... So imagine, you have something like three row of a table, you can access to the page, and add information in a div or an input in these row, click a button to save the information and when someone will open the page from another client, he should see the information updated...Can you help me with this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114951/discussion-between-cirora-and-ivorujavaboy).

Answer (score 0):

To directly address your *updated* question:
No, there is no way to write to the server filesystem without establishing something on the server back-end to handle that. the way http security works, the client doesn't get access to the server like that. However, there are multiple back-end (or "middle-tier") systems you can set up to handle this. One old method was something called WebDAV. You can search for a WebDAV implementation for your preferred platform - there are several (including some server-side javascript-based ones.)